# response time in restassured

Tags: testing, rest-assured, response-time

i have been successful in capturing api response time using restassured .time() method and but i noticed that the response time returned in restassured is slightly higher than the same request if sent using postman or soapui. 
i looked everywhere on why restassured is taking too long but didnt find any answers, i also looked on how to reduce the restassured overhead thinking that may be the cause but also no success finding that up.
please any suggestions may help here to find why response time in restassured is higher comparing to other tools

this is my restassured call and i tried all the time functions in restassured to compare

```
Response Response = given().contentType(MediaType.TEXT_XML).accept(MediaType.TEXT_XML).body(content).log().all()
            .when().post("https://myurl.com").then().log().all()
            .extract().response();

logger.info(Response.getTime());
logger.info(Response.getTimeIn(TimeUnit.SECONDS));
logger.info(Response.time());
logger.info(Response.timeIn(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
```

Comment: Are you seeing a noticeable increase in the response time? Testing with Postman and Rest Assured when measuring response times are within a ~5% difference for me when testing various APIs I work with. Even using Postman, I see noticeable differences in first response compared to subsequent responses where first response time is way higher then second or third.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by the [docs](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#measuring-response-time) the value is not precise, especially when the JVM is cold. You should regard the time measurement as an approximation rather than fact. For example it can be useful to track statistics (on a CI server) over longer periods of time to find deviations such as sudden spikes related to a specific commit. The reason why you should not regard this as a precise measurement is because REST Assured's response time measurement includes a lot of processing such  JVM/Groovy class load times. You should probably using something like [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) if you really want to get proper benchmarks.

Comment: I see around 4s of overhead on a cold RestAssured test. Measuring the time of IO request/response roundtrip shouldn't be dependant on some load class. On a cold JVM with OkHttp, the measure is is closer to the reality. `Stopwatch started = Stopwatch.createStarted(); Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute(); assertThat(started.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)).isLessThanOrEqualTo(100);`, Using native tools like curl : `Done curl localhost:8080/poke  0.01s user 0.01s system 59% cpu 0.023 total`.

Comment: Well I'm open for suggestions on what can be done to improve it. If you look at the code I've tried to put the timing measurements as close the actual request/response processing as possible. But I could of course be doing something wrong :)

Comment: Yes I barely looked at the code, but I'm quite unfamiliar with groovy but I'd think the `TimingFilter` is where it go wrong as it can measure other filters around the actual call and that means a lot of groovy's own reflection code. Besides in the `RestAssuredHttpBuilder#doRequest` performs additional stuff around the call, so this filter is measuring the client code and the IO roundtrip. Imho the measure should be done there : `this.client.execute(reqMethod, delegate.getContext())`.

Comment: Maybe there's a way to warming up groovy ? I came around this issue because I was running a single timing test. The only option I had was to initiate a first hand call, but this is not a proper fix. And even when warmed up, a simple OKHttp call has less overhead. And I'm not even using the beta `EventListener` api for metrics.

Comment: Thanks Brice! If it's not too much to ask maybe you could create an issue with all the details you've found here? https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues

Comment: Yup I will do it, I have set a small piece of code demonstrating the issue on my own rest endpoints, I think changing the URL to example.com will demonstrate just as well ;)

Comment: I created the ticket, sorry it took so long : https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/961